# How get consecutives weeks in a group in df python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the follow df_m:

```
time_series                     date   sales  
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-01-17  4.0
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-01-24  4.0
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-01-31  1.0
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-02-07  1.0
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-02-21  0.0 
store_0051_item_90944673    2021-02-07  0.0
store_0051_item_90944673    2021-02-28  0.0
store_0051_item_90944673    2021-03-07  0.0
```

I tried use the follow code:

```
df_m['date1'] = df_m['date'].shift(-1)
df_m['time_series1'] = df_m['time_series'].shift(-1)
df_m['check'] = (df_m['time_series1'] == df_m['time_series']) & (df_m['date'] < df_m['date1'])
```

But, this code don't return what I want. I would like that a new column with "True" or "False" with the follow logic:

```
time_series                     date    sales  check
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-01-17  4.0     True
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-01-24  4.0     True
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-01-31  1.0     True
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-02-07  1.0     True
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-02-21  0.0     False
store_0050_item_90944672    2021-03-07  0.0     False
store_0051_item_90944673    2021-02-07  0.0     False
store_0051_item_90944673    2021-02-28  0.0     True
store_0051_item_90944673    2021-03-07  0.0     True
```

See, I want a return 'True' only the weeks consecutives and 'False' only the weeks that the next row not is consecutive for each group in 'time_series', in another words, isolated weeks without another consecutive one I want it to return 'False' if not 'True'.
How Can I do this?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Final solution will give you the expected result :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but when I have consecutives dates, but 'time_series' field is different comparing the last row, is returning 'True', but are dates isolateds, so should be 'False'. How Can I repair this? I tried the suggestion by NK, but also didn't word :(

Comment: Can you add that example? I need for test cases so that solution can be modified

Comment: `(df.date.diff(1).abs().dt.days).le(7) | (df.date.diff(-1).abs().dt.days).le(7)` I guess it's due to using `fillna` use without fillna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['check'] = abs((df.date.shift(1) - df.date).dt.days).le(7) | abs((df.date.shift(-1) - df.date).dt.days).le(7)
```

OR

```
df['check'] = (df.date.diff(1).abs().dt.days).le(7) | (df.date.diff(-1).abs().dt.days).le(7)
```

---

|  | time_series | date | sales | check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | store_0050_item_90944672 | 2021-01-17 | 4.0 | True |
| 1 | store_0050_item_90944672 | 2021-01-24 | 4.0 | True |
| 2 | store_0050_item_90944672 | 2021-01-31 | 1.0 | True |
| 3 | store_0050_item_90944672 | 2021-02-07 | 1.0 | True |
| 4 | store_0050_item_90944672 | 2021-02-21 | 0.0 | False |
| 5 | store_0050_item_90944672 | 2021-03-07 | 0.0 | False |
| 6 | store_0051_item_90944673 | 2021-02-07 | 0.0 | False |
| 7 | store_0051_item_90944673 | 2021-02-28 | 0.0 | True |
| 8 | store_0051_item_90944673 | 2021-03-07 | 0.0 | True |

---

By taking `year week`:

```
u = df.date.dt.strftime('%U').astype(int)
out = u.eq(u.shift(1)+1) | u.eq(u.shift(-1)-1)
```

---

### Update:

I got it now Isolated dates here mean they don't have the same time series. So you are looking to group them by `time series` and then apply the logic.

This will do the job:

```
df.groupby('time_series')['date'].apply(lambda x:  (x.diff(1).abs().dt.days).le(7) | (x.diff(-1).abs().dt.days).le(7))
```

---

### UPDATE:

```
import numpy as np
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
u = df.date.dt.strftime('%U').astype(int)
df['check'] = df.groupby(['time_series', (u != u.shift()+1).cumsum()]).transform(lambda x: True if len(x)>1 else False)
```

Comment: I didn't understand the final solution. Over the table: df['check'] = abs((df.date - df.date.shift(-1)).dt.days).fillna(0).le(7), not is the final solution?

Comment: Yeah actually when you will shift by -1 you are comparing the current value with the next value so your last row won't have anything to match with.

Comment: @Vivian: what part you are not getting?

Comment: `time_series                     date sales    check
store_0015_item_85261505 2021-04-18 9.0     True
store_0016_item_85261505 2021-01-24 12.0        True
store_0029_item_85261505 2021-01-24 4.0         True
store_0046_item_85261505 2020-09-13 4.0     False
store_0058_item_85261505 2020-11-08 13.0        False`

Why return 'True' in 3 rows? Are isolateds dates.

Comment: @Vivian: Please try the updated solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.isocalendar().week
df['check'] = ((m.eq(m.shift(-1) - 1)) | (m.eq(m.shift(1) + 1))).fillna((m.eq(m.shift(-1) - 1)))
```

Comment: Only detail: `time_series               date  check
store_0015_item_85261505   2021-04-18    <NA>`

Can I leave 'True' or 'False' in first row? Returned <NA>.

Comment: I guess it's better to use `.bfill()` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :D

Comment: Another detail. Sorry my questions, but when I have consecutives dates, but 'time_series' field is different comparing the last row, is returning 'True', but are dates isolateds, so should be 'False'. How Can I repair this?

Comment: I guess that's because of `bfill`.  Not sure if this will work for every scenario or not but I've updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233149/discussion-between-vivian-and-nk03).